# Get encoding of string read from file

Tags: perl, powershell, encoding

I'm trying to convert a perl script into a powershell script. I'm having problems with a part of it when the script is reading a log file and has to get the encoding of the file.

Here is the perl code:

```
sub get_encoding {
my $f = shift;
my $fh;
return "ASCII" if (!open ($fh,"<",$f));
my $b = "";
my $n = read ($fh,$b,2);
close ($fh);
return "UTF-16" if ($b eq "\x{ff}\x{fe}");
return "ASCII";
}
```

it is called like so:

```
get_encoding ($l->{file})
```

Where $l->{file} is a path to the log file.

Can anyone explain what is going on, especially in this line:

```
return "UTF-16" if ($b eq "\x{ff}\x{fe}");
```

And if anyone knows a good way to do this in powershell, any tips are much apreciated.

Gísli

Comment: http://enwp.org/UTF-16#Byte_order_encoding_schemes

Comment: That line actually looks like a bug to me.  I think it ought to read `return "UTF-16" if ($b eq "\xFF\xFE");` - i.e.: it should be comparing the bytes read in from the file to a byte string rather than a character string.  `"\xE9"` is a byte string containing the single byte 0xE9. `"\x{E9}"` is a character string containing the character at Unicode codepoint 0+00E9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program reads and exams the first 2 bytes of the given file to decide whether it should return string "ASCII" or "UTF-16".

Here are some more detail description:

If the file cannot be opened, for whatever reason, it returns "ASCII". (Weird, but that's what it does.)

```
return "ASCII" if (!open ($fh,"<",$f));
```

If the file is opened as file handle `$fh`, `read($fh, $b, 2)` the first 2 (8-bit) bytes in to variable `$b`. The return value of `read`, which means the number of bytes actually read, gets stored to the variable `$n`, although it is never used latter.

```
my $b = "";
my $n = read ($fh,$b,2);
```

The file handle `$fh` gets to be `close`ed right after the read.

```
close ($fh);
```

If the value of `$b` is exactly "\x{ff}\x{fe}", the "UTF-16" is returned. Although it would be more exact to return "UTF-16BE". `\x{..}` is the representation of bytes by its hex value. Thus there are two bytes in `"\x{ff}\x{fe}"`, not 10 or 12.

```
return "UTF-16" if ($b eq "\x{ff}\x{fe}");
```

At last, if `$b` is not equal to "\x{ff}\x{fe}", "ASCII" is returned.

```
return "ASCII";
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://franckrichard.blogspot.com/2010/08/powershell-get-encoding-file-type.html

```
    function Get-FileEncoding{
    [CmdletBinding()] Param (
[Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True)] [string]$Path) 
    [byte[]]$byte = get-content -Encoding byte -ReadCount 4 -TotalCount 4 -Path $Path
    if ( $byte[0] -eq 0xef -and $byte[1] -eq 0xbb -and $byte[2] -eq 0xbf )
    { Write-Output 'UTF8' }
    elseif 
    ($byte[0] -eq 0xfe -and $byte[1] -eq 0xff)
    { Write-Output 'Unicode' }
    elseif ($byte[0] -eq 0 -and $byte[1] -eq 0 -and $byte[2] -eq 0xfe -and $byte[3] -eq 0xff)
    { Write-Output 'UTF32' }
    elseif ($byte[0] -eq 0x2b -and $byte[1] -eq 0x2f -and $byte[2] -eq 0x76)
    { Write-Output 'UTF7'}
    else
    { Write-Output 'ASCII' }}
```

Comment: The part where it says Unicode is not accurate, as it is a character set, not an encoding. The code should make a distinction between UTF-16BE and UTF-16LE. Please fix.

Comment: That part related to UTF-8 is slightly incorrect, as UTF-8 doesn't need a byte order mark (it's a byte sequence; although one might be encoded to mark it as UTF-8). In the end, UTF-8 was designed to be exchangeable with ASCII, if no characters beyond U+007f are used.

Comment: @daxim & sstn see link in my answer, there is a more accurate script. Is not soup of my kitchen but a good starting point for better accurate scripts

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Isn't there a simpler way to check this. Can I do the check by reading two bytes and check them like it is done in the perl script?

Answer (score 1):

the script read two bytes previously into $b from $f : `my $n = read ($fh,$b,2);`

the line in question test these two bytes whether they are literally FF and FE

I guess FF, FE is the byte order mark for UTF-16 little endian encoding 
see here http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html